# How to create a new user with each button click of a register form with Java?

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, actionlistener

I have a RegisterGui class which is my java swing gui. It has a username field, password field, and a register button.

I would like to have it so that each time the register button is clicked, it creates a new user and saves the username and password for that user. The problem is that I don't know where I should be creating the new users, inside the button clicked method? I would like to be able to access user information possibly from my main method.

I was told to use an ArrayList to hold the users, but not sure where to declare that list and maintain when the register button is clicked. This is what I have so far, not using an ArrayList.

```
private void onLogin(ActionEvent e) {
    User user1 = new User(userText.getText(), passwordText.getText());
    System.out.println(user1.getUserName());
    System.out.println(user1.getPassword());
    successLabel.setText("Success!");
}
```

[image]

Comment: You create the List inside an application model.  An application model is made up of one or more plain Java getter/setter classes.  You pass an instance of your application model to your view and action listeners.

Comment: `private List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();` as an instance variable would do it

Comment: So I wouldn't create the list either in the RegisterGui class nor the User class?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a static member for the users somewhere in your code, possibly even in `RegisterGui`:

```
protected static List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
```

And you could create a getter and an adder:

```
public static List<User> getUsers() {
    return users;
}

public static void addUser(User user) {
    users.add(User);
}
```

And you can call `RegisterGui.getUsers` or `RegisterGui.addUser` wherever you want, including the `main` method or the register button's click. However, it would be great if you separated the backend logic from the frontend display code.

Comment: When the button is clicked, I added this to the method:
 Users.add(new User(userText.getText(), passwordText.getText()));
successLabel.setText("Success!");